# Having trouble understanding how to use an API, any advice?

Tags: javascript, api, rest

As the image shows below:
[Site: https://docs.thecatapi.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGzZt.png)

```
//Cat Command
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}cat`)) {
    message.channel.send("Looking for a kitty...").then (m => {
        m.edit(`Found one!`)
    })
    fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")
    .then(res => res.json()).then(body => {
        if(!body) return message.reply(" whoops. I broke, try again!")

        const catEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(" Meowww..")
        .setColor(`#a87f32`)
        .setURL(body.url)
        .setImage(body.url)
        message.channel.send(catEmbed)
    })
}
```

I'm using this code as shown above, although it does not return the url, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). What do you see in the web console? My guess is you're getting some kind of error, most likely one saying that the Same Origin Policy prevented access to the endpoint (though it come be something else).

Comment: It's not *the* problem, bit it's *a* problem: Your code is falling prey to the footgun in the [`fetch` API](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html): You need to check whether the HTTP operation succeeded before trying to process the body as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response provides an *array*, not just a single object. You want to use `url` on the objects that are in the array. For instance, to use the first `url`, you'd use `body[0].url`. But it's an array, so it could be empty (`body[9]` would give you `undefined`) or it could have more than one entry.

You also want to check HTTP success (`fetch` only rejects on *network* errors, not HTTP errors; [more here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)) and handle rejection:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}cat`)) {
    message.channel.send("Looking for a kitty...").then(m => {
        m.edit(`Found one!`)
    }); // *** If this promise can be rejected, you want a `.catch` here too
    fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
        }
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(body => {
        if(!body || !body[0]) {
            message.reply(" whoops. I broke, try again!");
        } else {
            const [{url}] = body; // Or `const url = body[0].url;`
            const catEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(" Meowww..")
            .setColor(`#a87f32`)
            .setURL(url)
            .setImage(url);
            message.channel.send(catEmbed);
        }
    })
    .catch(e => {
        // ...do something with the error, or just ignore it; either
        // way, this prevents you getting an unhandled rejection
        // error in the console
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in the sintax. Try debugging it using `console.log()` to make sure you are getting the server;

```
fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search").then(res => res.json()).then(body => {
    if(!body) return;

    /* Check the response content */
    console.log(body);
}).catch(err => {
    /* Handle any possible error that may be occoring */
    console.log(err);
});
```

Now you may debug it from browser console.